# PyBrain, NFQ customizing Network

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

At the moment I'm using the NFQ algorithm from pybrain. I would like to experiment with different kind of networks (number of neurons in the hidden layer, e.g) Is there a possibility to do this?

```
self.controller = ActionValueNetwork(3,3)
```

For example, let me just set the input and output neurons.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I've found that it is not possible to do this with functions provided by pyBrain itself, because there is only one `ActionValueNetwork` constructor.

But you could add some functionality to pyBrain yourself to reach this goal. I have been looking into this part of pyBrain yesterday and it seemed not too hard to do this.
look at the file `pybrain/rl/learners/valuebased/interface.py` for the `ActionValueNetwork` class.
You could add your own constructor there with more arguments and call `BuildNetwork()` with it.
For the `BuildNetwork()` function look in `pybrain/tools/shortcuts.py`

I hope this helps!